# using a Raspberry Pi 3 Win IOT to communicate usb to usb

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I have been trying to use a USB to TTL cable to allow my Raspberry Pi to write a string to the usb attached to my pc. The goal is to use Voice Recognition to send a login number to a device.  The device is currently using a NFC plugged into the usb slot on the device.  I would like to do away with the card reader and use voice.  Are there any components  I am missing? I have the code to write to a serial device but during testing the PC does not think the device is started correctly.

I have tested the NFC Card reader and I can plug it into my pc and open notepad to get the string it sends, but so far the raspberry pi does not.

Please any help.
mscott161

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish, and how, and what errors you recieve.

Comment: Do you mean to use a USB-to-serial cable between Raspberry Pi and PC, like [this](https://shop.clickandbuild.com/cnb/shop/ftdichip?productID=126&op=catalogue-product_info-null&prodCategoryID=296)?

Comment: @jonasfh I am trying to communicate over a usb cable from the Raspberry Pi to a usb port on a PC. The data is always a string with a line return at the end.  I get no errors in my code using a USB-TTL cable but the data is not captured by the PC.  In a nutshell, I want to plug my Raspberry Pi to my PC via a USB cable open up notepad and send a string from the Raspberry Pi and have it show in notepad on the PC.

Comment: @RitaHan I have tried the cable and have burn one raspberry pi and one cable. I do not think I have it wired correctly. it does show on my PC as a COM port but the PC says it is not connected correctly.

Comment: @MichaelScott What's your cable's output voltage to raspberry pi and which pins you connected?

Comment: @RitaHan I am using the Adafruit 954. Have changed the config file in root folder of the SD Card with WinIOT to have enable_uart=1 at the end. I have the White wire in GPIO 14 and the Green in GPIO 15, Black is to Ground.  Have the Prolific COM3 show up on my desktop but the Raspberry Pi does not see it as a USB/COM port for Serial.  Please refer to the comment to jonasfh above to see purpose.

Comment: **"it does show on my PC as a COM port but the PC says it is not connected correctly"**  Have you installed PL2303HX drivers successfully? Or have you test the cable by serial port tool before developing your own app?

Comment: @RitaHan I have the Adafruit 954 showing successfully on the PC but the SerialSample from Microsoft does not show any Serial devices to connect to.  I have read articles that the GPIO pins are different in Raspberry Pi 3 (which I am using) than the Raspberry Pi 2. I believe the problem lies in the wires to the GPIO.  Does anyone know how to get the Adafruit 954 connected to the Raspberry Pi 3 so it shows as a Serial/USB device?

Comment: @RitaHan The problem is the Raspberry Pi is not seeing the Adafruit as a USB/Serial Device not the PC.